# cin wont work in loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, cin

Ok so im trying to learn c++, and i was making a simulation but the cin wont work for me :(

```
void Simulation::initialize(){
    cout<<"Choose number of players: " <<endl;
    cin>> numberOfPlayer;
    string name;
    int accurasy;
    int life;
    for(int index=0; index <=numberOfPlayer;++index){
        cout<<"Enter name, accurasy and life for player"<<index +1 <<": " <<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cin>>accurasy;
        cin>>life;
        Kombatant comb(name,accurasy,life);
        vect->push_back(comb);

    }
}
```

This is the code that wont work for me. Im trying to add players to the simulation. Everything works as expected until i get in to the for loop. For some reason it only works in the first looping until i get to life. Then it skips the life input and every input after that (every input in all the loops). Anyone have any ideas what the problem is ?

Comment: add a comment if you want me to provide any additional information about the program

Comment: Read up on how cin works, especially on mixed input because the cin works a bit funky when you have strings and integers together. Certain characters are left behind in the input buffer and causes your behaviour. It flags a failbit and then causes the program to exit. It's been a while since i touched C++ but I remember having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the last newline is still in the input buffer. So when you loop the input of the name will see the newline and give you an empty input.

You have to tell the input stream to explicitly skip it:

```
// all your input...

// Skip over the newline in the input buffer
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```